# Linux server terminal - rows of tildes, can't write commands?

Tags: command-line, vi

I'm pretty new - came across this problem.  My webserver terminal is looking weird, there are some code echoes and then rows and rows of tilde. Where I type would be at the green square, but nothing I type commands or otherwise do anything.  Pressing enter jumps down the square and clears a tilde but does not make any difference.

Tried to run clear screen commands ( ctrl-l and such ) doesn't do anything.  Searching about tildes just brings up the meaning of a tilde, not whatever this is.  Any way to kill what is happening?

[image: terminal snapshot]

Comment: Type `:q` and see.

Comment: this command just acts like ordinary text also

Comment: You need to press enter after the that, you are in vi editing mode. If you want to discard changes made to the file, try `:q!`

Comment: Ok, I did that.  looks like :quit<enter> is what the terminal told me.  When I do that, this message comes up E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be in [Vi Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) editing mode (look down below the screen: `-- INSERT --`, is for insert mode).

To change editing mode, you need to press ESC key first. And then to quit/exit vi altogether without saving you can type `:q!` and press ENTER.

Vi is a widely used command line text file editor comes with almost every linux distros. You should take some time to learn it: [How to Use the vi Editor](https://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/vi.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not actually a network administrator, I just have to use the terminal sometimes and figured this was the best place to ask.  Now I think I have a better idea what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

### This is Expected Behavior from Vi and Vim

This is not a picture of a TTY or PTY. What you're seeing is vi in insert mode with a screen port showing more lines than currently exist in the file or buffer. The editor will show non-existent lines at the end of a file/buffer with the `~` character to avoid confusing them with empty or whitespace-only lines.

Aside from screen-resize issues, you may need to:

1. Exit insert mode with <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>.

   ***Note***: Sometimes vim is doing something programmatic, in which case you may need to do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate the script, followed by <kbd>ESC</kbd>.
2. Exit the file with `:q`, `:q!`, `:wq`, `ZZ`, or other similar command, depending on whether or not you want to write the buffers back to disk first or not. See [usr_02](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_02.html#02.7) of the Vim manual for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the extra information!  tapping ctrl-c a couple times helped trigger instructions at the bottom for typing the :q bit.

Comment: isn't this behavior common to Classic vi?

Comment: @erreka Possibly, but I have no way of testing it. If you have a copy of the original vi, fire it up and let us know. Otherwise, I'd prefer to stick with statements that are provably true on modern Linux distributions or OS X, both of which generally provide vi through some variation of (or links to) Vim. Your mileage and specific distribution may vary.

Comment: The behavior is the same in classic ex/vi and the busybox clone, except for the bottom message.

Comment: @erreka Thanks for testing it. I've updated the slug line accordingly.